# uWebSockets (C++): secure wss server

Tags: c++, ssl, websocket, server, openssl

I am using uWebSockets in C++ to host a WebSocket server. However,  I need it to be a secure `wss` server instead of simply a `ws` server.

I have tried this code:

```
uS::TLS::Context tls = uS::TLS::createContext ("./cert.perm", "./key.perm", "passphrase");

if (h.listen (9002, tls)) {
    cout << "Game server listening on port 9002" << endl;
    h.run();
}
```

I am using this shell command to generate the certificate and key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 30
```

I then tried connecting to my remote server using `wss://address` instead of the usual `ws://address`, however, it cannot connect.

Any ideas why? Thanks

**UPDATE #1**

The `tls` variable seems to be actually `NULL`, so it looks like the certificate part isn't working.

**UPDATE #2**

I got the file extensions wrong in the code, they're meant to be `pem` instead of `perm`. However, the server will now not establish a connection on both `wss` and `ws`.

**UPDATE #3**

After fixing the issue mentioned above, the `tls` variable is now `1` instead of `0` (which I assumed was `NULL`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a web browser ws-client to connect to wss://address, try checking if the browser is the problem. It happened to me that I had created my own certificates, but the browser blocks the connection as they are not certified by any CA.
Enter in your browser something like: "https://address", and add a security exception for your "address".

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use uWebSockets for SSL/TLS, however... I would consider separating the TLS/SSL concern from the main application.

Separating the TLS/SSL layer from the app allows you to update the TLS/SSL without recompiling the application as well as simplifies the codebase.

I would recommend using a TLS/SSL proxy or tunnel while having the app bind locally to the loopback address or to a unix socket.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I may go for this option, but the moment I would appreciate just an answer to my specific issue.

Comment: PS I added an update with more info to the question.

Comment: @iONinja, a few comments: 1. is it possible the path names are misspelled (note that UpperCase vs. lower case matters on some systems)? 2. why do you have space between the function and the parenthesis (is it a copy error)?

Comment: 1. Yes! I got the filename wrong. The extensions were meant to be `pem` instead of `perm` in the code. However, the server now won't establish a connection for both `ws` and `wss`. It looks like I've narrowed it down to the core of the issue. 2. Erm, that is just my coding style. I realise now that it's doesn't make much sense, but I seem to be used to it now :P.

Comment: PS See Update #3 for more details.